# Can't upload a file with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm having no luck uploading a file with protractor. Just need to fill out a simple form and click a submit button, which then posts the form to a different url:

```
  it('can upload file', function(){
    var fileToUpload = './example.txt',
        absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
        file = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

    element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
    element(by.css('button[type="submit"]')).click().then(function(){
        console.log('button clicked');
    });

});
```

Here's the form markup:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload" class="upload ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file">
    <button type="submit" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

It appears from watching the test run that the input is filled in and the submit button is clicked, but then instead of posting the form to the proper url:

```
http://localhost/upload
```

Chrome appears to navigate to that url but just says "The webpage is not available" in the test window. Submitting the form manually works, the post to /upload works as expected and give you a confirmation message.

What I want to do is just wait for the upload to process and write another test to check the confirmation message, but I can't seem to get this far. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here: when you have the wrong file path or name being sent in to the file input this "page not found" error is what protractor will show instead of any sort of useful message or indication that no such file exists before you submit the form.

In my case I had the wrong directory, instead of "./example.txt" I needed "../example.txt" and it now works as expected.

Comment: If you want to see what is going wrong it may be helpful to add a _second_ argument to `then`, which is the function called if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I think you need to setFileDetector for it to work in chrome.

```
// set file detector
var remote = require('../../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());


var fileToUpload = '../sample.txt';
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

// Unhide file input
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';  arguments[0].style.opacity = 1", fileElem.getWebElement());

fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);

// take a breath 
browser.driver.sleep(100);

// click upload button
element(by.css('button[data-ng-click="uploadFile(file)"]')).click(); // does post request
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach:

```
this.uploadFile = function(filename){
    var filetoUpload = '../attachments/'+filename;
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, filetoUpload);
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
};"
```